# Require SSL phpMyAdmin - necessary for .local before pushing live?

Tags: ssl, phpmyadmin

We are building our site locally. When we create users within phpMyAdmin should we 'require SSL' since we have an SSL certificate on our domain?

Do we need to do anything 'special' when building our site locally for a HTTPS/ SSL site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "REQUIRE SSL" radio button on the "User accounts" tab is regarding the MySQL user and doesn't have anything to do with whether your site will require (or support) HTTPS. MySQL servers can require incoming connections to connect over SSL. In most cases, your MySQL server shouldn't be accepting connections from external sources, which may in some cases reduce the usefulness of requiring SSL connections, of course depending heavily on your network configuration and other factors

It sounds like what you're looking for is to configure your webserver to use an SSL certificate, which (unless you're using absolute URLs or picky CMS software) you should just be able to turn on in the production deployment if that's your desire.