# Locked out of phpmyadmin by require ssl

Tags: php, ssl, phpmyadmin

I clicked "require ssl" in phpmyadmin on my server and it locked me out. I've searched everywhere for any file I can change to reverse this, but all the old methods have been discontinued in the newer versions of phpmyadmin (4.6+). I have scoured through all the files I could get my hands on, but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Which version of PMA do you use? Add the version to your question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433818/require-ssl-phpmyadmin-necessary-for-local-before-pushing-live --> `The "REQUIRE SSL" radio button on the "User accounts" tab is regarding the MySQL user and doesn't have anything to do with whether your site will require (or support) HTTPS.` Ie, [this setting](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl)

Comment: I believe its 4.6.?... I'm locked out so I can't check. Whatever is default with ubuntu 16.04.

The site connects through mysqli for all of its functions so the inability to connect to phpmyadmin prevents the site from being loaded.

Comment: fvu - I found that documentation as well but cannot find a single file with those parameters to manipulate

Comment: Had to rebuild my server, reinstalling phpmyadmin didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly for your version of mysql but one simple way to solve this on mariadb/mysql is to enable ssl connections on your server. As a side effect, it will render your server more secure if you force users to use SSL... The way to do this is to:

1) Create a certificate for your server if not already done. There are lots of site to explain how to do this. http://www.openssl.org would be a good start.

2) Modify the mariadb configuration /etc/mysql/my.cnf for the server to point to your certificate:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And add/uncomment the following lines (and change the path to the SSL files):

```
ssl=true
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
```

3) Restart mariadb/mysql:

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

4) Loggin to mariadb using ssl:

```
sudo mysql --ssl -u root -p
```

It will ask for the root password of mariadb/mysql.

5) And finally remove the "REQUIRE SSL" constraint for the root user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
QUIT;
```

After which your can log as root with phpmyadmin as you could before.

I hope this helps anyone in your situation as I fell in the same trap myself.